# Pipe vendor js files from Bower and own js files into unique stream in Gulp

Tags: javascript, bower, gulp

I'd like to grab my vendor js files from bower dependencies, and, along with my own js files, pipe through some other tasks and concat them into one .js file. And then do the same for Sass files.

How could I achieve that? I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
   return gulp.src([
        mainBowerFiles(gulpFilter('*.js')),
        'app/js/*.js'
        ])
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(concat('app.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});
```

It throws this error:

```
TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
```

But it works if I have this, for example:

```
gulp.src([
    'app/js/etc.js',
    'app/js/main.js'
])
```

..and in the following case, it throws a different error (but no error without uglify()):

```
gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(gulpFilter('*.js')))
```

error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

How do I better debug this? Should I separate vendor / own js files in different streams?

**update**

I'm working now with two streams, and merging them later on with `event-stream`, like this:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {

    var jsFilter = gulpFilter('*.js');
    var vendorFiles = gulp.src(mainBowerFiles()) // don't read
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'));

    var appFiles = gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'));

    return es.concat(vendorFiles, appFiles)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});
```

It works great, but I'm not able to handle the order of the files. Obviously I'd like that the vendor code come before my code at the destination's `app.js`, but that's doesn't happen. I created a thread about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768789/order-when-concat-streams-with-event-stream-in-gulp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it with [gulp-event-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/event-stream) and [gulp-order](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-order). Intrigues me a little that gulp-order is trending downward at https://www.npmjs.org, though.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {

    var jsFilter = gulpFilter('*.js');
    var vendorFiles = gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'));

    var appFiles = gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'));

    return eventStream.concat(vendorFiles, appFiles)
        .pipe(order([
            "vendor.js",
            "app.js"
        ]))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});
```

Comment: I've also found `gulp-order` to be helpful with `gulp-inject` to make sure I'm injecting jquery before bootstrap before any other bower dependencies. `gulp.src(mainBowerFiles()).pipe(order(['**jquery**', '**bootstrap**']))`

Answer (score 1):

mainBowerFiles() returns an array. gulp.src is expecting an array of strings, not nested arrays, which is likely the cause of the first problem. You could try the following instead:

```
gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(gulpFilter('*.js')).push('app/js/*.js'))
```

I'm not sure what's causing the unhandled error event, but you could try using gulp-debug to get more information.

Comment: Good insight! But that returned another error: `Invalid glob argument: 4`, and `debug()` doesn't show anything, neither `debug({verbose:true})`. And I decided to use 2 different streams (for vendor and app) and merge them later on (with `gulp-event-stream` - my new struggle), so I'm able to apply tasks for both streams independently.

Comment: hm, maybe mainBowerFiles() doesn't like gulpFilter. have you looked at the common options? You may need to supply an object with a path. https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files#common-options

Comment: hmm, I might try that later, now I'm ok with keeping the streams separated initially , and merge them later on with gulp event-stream - don't you think that is a better practice (in general terms)? My headache now is about keeping the code in the correct order - I just did an update to this post.

Comment: Merging makes sense now that you're applying different pipes to the sources. Though you should be able to consolidate your concats after the merge to save a step.