# Order when concat streams with event-stream in Gulp

Tags: stream, gulp

In this Gulp task, the vendorFiles code is placed after the appFiles code in the dest style.css file.

Is that because the appFiles stream runs faster? How to have the vendorFiles code come before as expected?

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {

    var vendorFiles = gulp.src(mainBowerFiles()) // don't read
        .pipe(gulpFilter('*.css'));

    var appFiles = gulp.src('app/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(prefix('> 5%'));

    return es.concat(vendorFiles, appFiles)
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved it with `gulp-order`

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {

    var jsFilter = gulpFilter('*.js');
    var vendorFiles = gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'));

    var appFiles = gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'));

    return eventStream.concat(vendorFiles, appFiles)
        .pipe(order([
            "vendor.js",
            "app.js"
        ]))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});
```